# Special "Move" with version History

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I am trying to move a Library from SharePoint 2013, which is on Server A, to SharePoint 2016, which is on Server B, WITHOUT losing the history.

Is that Possible? If so, how?

The "Move" way only works with libraries in the same Server (same version of SharePoint).

Same with the "Save as Template with Content".

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use Sharegate or migrate SP 2013 -> 2016 :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use a third party tool to move libraries from SP2013 to SP2016, or you will need to migrate the entire site collection with the database attach method.  There is not away to do a backup / restore of a library from SP2013 to SP2016.